# Adafruit RTClib TimeSpan calculation fails on ESP32

Tags: c++, esp32, real-time-clock

I'm currently trying to measure remaining time until a given timestamp using Adafruit's [RTClib library](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib). My RTC module is a DS3231.
here is my TimeSpan object in code:

```
TimeSpan remaining = next.depart - rtc.now();
```

However when i try to print the remaining minutes i get no data.
Here is my code that prints the output:

```
  Serial.println(String("current time: " + rtc.now().timestamp()));
  Serial.println(String("targetTime: " + next.depart.timestamp()));
  Serial.println(String("remaining time: " + remaining.minutes()));
```

And the output is right except for the remaining time in minutes:

```
current time: 2020-12-06T05:38:55
target time: 2020-12-06T05:42:30
aining time:
```

Notice that the last line is cut off in the serial output and the remaining minutes aren't displayed. current time and target time are both correct in the readout.
I can't perform any operations with the remaining time either:

```
if(remaining.minutes() >= 10)
```

In this case the condition is never met.
Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line of code:

```
  Serial.println(String("remaining time: " + remaining.minutes()));
```

is not doing what you think it's doing.

`remaining.minutes()` [returns type `int8_t`](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib/blob/master/RTClib.h#L224) not type `String`. You're adding it to a C character pointer to the C string `remaining time:`   - if the value is greater than the length of that string then the resulting pointer is invalid and you're lucky your program doesn't crash.

For instance, if `remaining.minutes()` were 3 then your output would be:

```
aining time:
```

Instead your code should look more like this:

```
  Serial.println("remaining time: " + String(remaining.minutes()));
```

or better:

```
  Serial.print("remaining time: ");
  Serial.println(remaining.minutes());
```

The second form has the benefit of avoiding unnecessary `String` object instantiations and allocating memory.

The reason your two lines:

```
  Serial.println(String("current time: " + rtc.now().timestamp()));
  Serial.println(String("targetTime: " + next.depart.timestamp()));
```

work is that the `timestamp()` method [returns a `String`](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib/blob/master/RTClib.h#L148), so adding a C character string to it results in string concatenation rather than adding an integer to a character pointer.

In these two cases your enclosing call to `String()` is superfluous and should be avoided:

```
  Serial.println("current time: " + rtc.now().timestamp());
  Serial.println("targetTime: " + next.depart.timestamp());
```

You're already computing `String` values; there's no need to make new `String` objects from them.

Find out what value `remaining.minutes()` is in order to answer your other question. It's likely an issue with the way `remaining` is computed, and is a matter for different question.

Comment: You were right. Casting the type to a string or character array seems to work.
I thought the type would be the same as in the timestamp.
Thank you for your answer.